# Threading with PyGTK

Tags: python, pygtk

To begin, I must say that I have searched for quite a long time on this subject and I probably know of most basic resources. I am attempting to use this: https://github.com/woodenbrick/gtkPopupNotify to add a system of notifications to a previously all command line program. Sadly, this usually will hang due to the fact that I perform lots of sleep operations, etc. I would assume it would work if I could get a system of threading in place. Essentially, all I want is to make a notification that doesn't interfere with any other operations of the program including other PyGTK components. Functions to make these notifications at the moment are looking like this for me:

```
    def showMessage(title, message):
        notifier1 = gtkPopupNotify.NotificationStack(timeout=4)
        notifier1.bg_color = gtk.gdk.Color("black")
        notifier1.fg_color = gtk.gdk.Color("white")
        notifier1.edge_offset_x = 5-27 #-27 for odd bugginess
        notifier1.edge_offset_y = 5
        notifier1.new_popup(title=title, message=message)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am becoming really fed up with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PyGTK, I highly recommend avoiding threads altogether. The GTK libraries aren't fully [thread-safe](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html) and, under Win-32, they don't support threads at all. So, trying to work with them ends up being a pain. You can get some really nice results by "faking it" using [Python generators](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pythrd/index.html) and the [gobject.idle_add() method](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq20.001.htp)

As an alternative to coding it yourself, you can also just use [Zenity](https://live.gnome.org/Zenity), which is a Gnome program for launching notification dialogs from the command line. This should be thread-safe.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["zenity", "--notification", "--text=You have been notified"])
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `gobject.idle_add()` in the course of a program? It doesn't appear so. Is there an alternative? I am currently using a terrible method of a global variable changing and an unending `gobject.timeout_add()` method to carry out a system of notifications while running another loop.

Comment: Absolutely, but be sure to pass `gobject.idle_add()` your generator's `next` method (ie `gobject.idle_add(myfakethread.next)`), and then in your generator, `yield True` as long as you want the fake-thread to run and `yield False` when it's finished.

Comment: When the method passed to `gobject.idle_add()` returns True, then it scheduled to be run again by GObject. When it returns False, it is not executed again. So, each call to `yield True`, in a sense, relinquishes control from the fake thread to GObject, and acts as a the point at which the fake-thread will resume next time GObject has some downtime.

Comment: Check the Zenity example I just added. That's probably the easiest solution. Otherwise, you'll have to edit the code of that library you're using in order to support these generator pseudothreads.